# Merge conflict on new line

Tags: git

Merge conflict when trying to merge a branch that has a new line in the contents of the same file.

These are the steps I took when creating my branches.

The conflict arises when I want to merge branch "bye" commit(C) with master commit(B). Both bye & master branches contain one ruby file. master has two lines and bye has three, the only difference in bye is a new line.

---

1- master Branch & commit(A):

puts "hi"

2- create hello branch & commit(B):

puts "hi"

puts "hello"

3- create bye branch & commit(C):

puts "hi"

puts "hello"

puts "bye"

4- merge hello with master(B):

puts "hi"

puts "hello"

5- merge bye with master(C):

---

Merge Conflict - content of Ruby file

puts "hi"

<<<<<<< HEAD

puts "hello"

=======

puts "hello"

puts "bye"

>>>>>>> bye

---

Branch Graph:

* 14f1df7 (bye) C

| * e5e0022 (HEAD -> master) B

|/
* 78a8dfe A

---

I didn't expect there to be a merge conflict as I didn't amend the original lines, just added a new one.

What am I doing wrong? Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to rebase branch C on top of the master branch instead of merge. You can read more from the Git documentation: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Answer (score 0):

Git sees different, overlapping-or-adjacent sets of additions since the `A`-commit base and wants you to say what the right merge result is.

```
puts "hi"
<<<<<<< HEAD
puts "hello"
=======
puts "hello"
puts "bye"
>>>>>>> bye
```

Get good with your merge tools it takes like two seconds to pick, for mine (vimdiff) it's literally three keystrokes, `3do`, pick the result from buffer 3, the "theirs" version. Typing `git mergetool` and saving afterwards bumps the total time to resolve this to five seconds.

Git doesn't examine the two sets of changes for internal similarities, the cases it could be certain of solving correctly for you if it did are so rare in practice and so easy to deal with that it's just not worth it.

Comment: Ok, so from my understanding the git merge/rebase is only useful if it's adding additional files rather than adding extra line(s) in the same files?

I'm just having a hard time wrapping my head round the point of merges if you can't even amend the same file.

Comment: Yes - I appreciate that I haven’t used this in a working environment, i’m just going by the book. I want to make sure I’m understanding it correctly before putting it into practice. If merging/rebasing branches with additional files that are separate from each other does not cause conflict but amending the same file does - that helps me understand it somewhat.